# Get Events from FullCalendar eventSource Object

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar

I'm using FullCalendar v5 and adding events using a Google Calendar event source. There is a function to add the events to the calendar using a given google calendar URL and a type, with a few extended props.

```
function getEventsFromGoogleCalendar(url, type){
                calendar.addEventSource({
                  googleCalendarId:url,
                  "readOnly":true,
                  "type":type,
                  "description":"",
                  "textColor":"black",
                  "className":"day-event",
                  "notes":""
                })
            }
```

This function works fine and the events show up on the calendar with all the correct properties, but I also want to be able to view the properties of individual events from the source, specifically the start date of each event. However, the events from the source do not show up in the array returned by:

```
calendar.getEvents()
```

So how can I iterate over the events in the calendar added by an eventSource, or at least view the start property of each?